# How to include hackage packages into Leksah

Tags: haskell, hackage, leksah

I wanted to start playing with [hExpat](http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/Hexpat/) for Xml I/O with Haskell.
However I didn't manage to find where to express to Leksah that I want to import that package into my current module.

Could you tell me how to achieve this ?

**EDIT**: still searching. There is some uselful info with this [Q&A](http://%3astackoverflow.com/questions/4170426/importing-haskell-modules) but it is only about Data.Time Data.Directory.

In my case, it is a downloaded, unzipped, Hackage package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing is, that you have to install the package. Just run cabal and type:

```
cabal install YOUR PACKAGE NAME HERE
```

Than, open Leksah, open the project's dependencies (package -> edit package -> dependencies) and enter your new package. Hit "save" afterwards. Now you have to reconfigure the package and afterwards it should work.

Comment: BTW, in your case it would be `cabal install hexpat`.

Comment: I run leksah with windows. It doesnt seem to know the cabal program.

Comment: Leksah reads cabal packages, but you still need to run cabal from the command line. Cabal is part of the Haskell Platform, which you should definitely install and use as your GHC, especially if you're running on Windows.

Comment: I had cabal not installed. I reinstalled the lattest Haskell Platform for windows. (There was a bug with NSIS installer lattest time I tried, now its ok).

Comment: It works like a charm once cabal is installed and updated :-) thx.